# Excel VBA changing properties of Form Control on Chart Tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have added an Label on my Chart tab, but when I try to change it's font all of the fields are greyed out. I have searched enough but didn't find any solution. I am attaching a screenshot of my chart tab.[image]

I want to change the font properties of this Label 10 on the chart tab. Is there a way I can access the properties by VBA.

To change the text I recorded a macro.

```
ActiveChart.Shapes("Label 10").Select
Selection.Characters.Text = "Mohit"
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
```

I tried the line code:

```
 Selection.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 20
```

but it doesn't work. is there a way to change the color and font size of this label ?

**Alternate that I am using now**

Now I am using Rectangle shape instead of Label. What I wanted to acheive was to display the name of the selected button  ( PV , Terrorism or SRCC ) as an indication that this button have been selected. So I clicked PV and my series changed and Rectangle displayed the name of selected Peril. 
[image]

Now if I select SRCC again the same thing happens.
[image]

For the code I only have to change the text of the rectangle every-time a button is pressed as I preset the font and size of text once which remains the same. I wasn't able to change the font and size of text with a label.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveChart.Shapes("Label 10").Select
With Selection
    .Characters.Text = "Mohit"
    .Font.Size = 20
End With
```

or you can avoid `Select`/`Selection` accessing your `Chart` object by its name:

```
With Charts("ChartName").Shapes("Label 10").TextFrame2.TextRange
    .Text = "Mohit"
    .Font.Size = 20
End With
```

Comment: .font.size throws an error "Object does not support this property"

Comment: I tested it on a [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194426.aspx) object, of which, via its `Shapes`property, get its "Label 10" [Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835842.aspx) object. This latter exposes a `TextFrame2` property returning a [TextFrame2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822136.aspx) object, whose `TextRange` property returns a [TextRange2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863528.aspx) object that finally exposes both a `Text` and a `Font` property

Comment: follow the object properties chain as per my last comment and see what you need.

Comment: Hi there.. I have added the error video to this link [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njehL-eMywY&feature=youtu.be). Just 40 sec video ..please have a look ..maybe will be able to spot the error. Meanwhile I am looking at the chart object property. Thanks for your help.

Comment: remove/comment that `On Error GoTo L` and see what line actually throws an error

Comment: `.Font.Size = 20 ` is throwing an error in the first code. And `With Charts("ChartName").Shapes("Label 10").TextFrame2.TextRange` in 2nd.

Comment: "ChartName" is to be substituted with your actual `Chart` name

Comment: Yes, Sorry I changed it to `ActiveChart.Shapes` ...Still the same error :(

Comment: I have found a way around it by using Rectangle shape instead of Label. Please do let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: So what's your actual code? And which line throws what error? We must be on the same page to have a chance of getting through it. Still both codes run with no errors on my excel 2013.

Comment: I have added an alternate below my question. If you want I can share a video of the error as well. The same line throws error. When i click debug the line turns yellow.